# How do I make markers draggable, labeled, and deletable? with Google maps javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markers

First of all, I know Google has documentation on how to complete all of these features, but even when I add the exact coding, the map no longer shows up, or it simply does not work.

I'm completely new to development, but the project I'm trying to complete is a Game of Thrones map, where other users may visit and add a marker, name the marker ( not a simple one-character label, more like an actual name, several characters long ), and delete their marker. If someone else adds a marker, I'd like to be able to see it. And vice versa, I want everyone's markers on the map to be visible.

So far, as a first step, all I'm trying to complete right now is creating markers and making them draggable. The map shows up fine, until I add the value "draggable:true" to the markers options. even though that's what the google documentation suggests.

Here's the google documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

And here's the page i'm trying to get the project to work on:http://jamie-jabbours-fabulous-project.webflow.io/

and here's the exact code i'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
          draggable: true
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB55_iwgWvg1_NjoIEqqXgeQOeDBrq8p5o&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm sure there is something very simple I'm doing wrong, but I can't see it.

Comment: So the first issue is to make the markers draggable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a comma..after `map` and before `draggable`

```
 function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map,
      draggable: true
    });
  }
```

Watch out for syntax bugs next time :)

Comment: yes! it works, thank you! I knew it would be something simple and dumb i was doing. :P thanks so much.

Comment: It s not dumb no worries - it happens more often than you can imagine. Hey...thank you :)